# Require path is not being accepted

Tags: include, require, require-once, php

> **Warning**: 
>   require_once(/var/www/html/test_lms/include/mysql.processing.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   **/var/www/html/test_lms/include/IMEXporter.class.php** on line
>   **513**
>
> **Fatal error**:  require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/var/www/html/test_lms/include/mysql.processing.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in
>   **/var/www/html/test_lms/include/IMEXporter.class.php** on line
>   **513**

**PHP from `IMEXporter.class.php` LINE 513 that is throwing the error**

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/mysql.processing.php";
```

The file is there.
The file is chmod 777.
The two files are both owned by the same user and group.
Why is php doing this to me?

---

<strike>The problem could be that `mysql.processing.php` itself is broken and even though php finds the file it refuses to retrieve it and instead throws a `Derp! cant find file. Derp.`. Kind of stupid to mislead me like that but its a possibility. I'm checking over my code now.</strike>

Nope, I tried erasing the entire script of `mysql.processing.php` and wrote

```
echo "Hello you impudent php";
```

and it still wont find the file. So its not a file broken issue. Also I fixed the file case issue. From uppercase P to lowercase and it still wont go for it. I tried to include a file by the name of test.php and it wont find that one either..

Comment: If the file's in the same dir as the script you're doing this from, why include the path at all? `.` is in your include path already.

Comment: So the file exists in the same directory as the IMEXporter.class.php script?

Comment: Yes, it is in the same directory.

Comment: Before the error message you posted there will usually be another error message that shows the reason why the fail can't be opened.

Comment: I made an edit to include that error. Its the same thing.

Comment: So the file is not there. Perhaps you are looking in the wrong folder?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking in the wrong file. Your first paste says `Warning: require_once(/var/www/html/test_lms/include/mysql.Processing.php):` but your code paste says `require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/mysql.processing.php";` => The capitalization doesn't match. Check, if another file requires `mysql.Processing.php`in your code. **EDIT** I mean in another file

Comment: I fixed the upper case `p` typo and the problem still persists.

Comment: To make that clear: You are looking in the wrong file :)

Comment: Nope, I am looking at the right file. I fixed the upper case `p` already as stated. The file exists in that directory. The problem however persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay here was the problem. Remember when I mentioned that my `mysql.processing.php` file could be broken? Well that was half the issue. Apparently php `require` returns the error `failed to open stream: No such file or directory.. etc` if it:

1) Cannot find the file.

2) It finds the file, but it cannot open it.

The error message is misleading and leads you to believe it is a path issue. Sometimes it is, but cases like mine, its just a syntax issue with the returned file. Now for the second half. I made the corrections to all my syntax errors on the `mysql.processing.php` but it still was not working.. So I just did a reboot of my server and now it works.

The second half of the problem is that php has a nasty tendency to cache php files. Often you can start editing a php script, fixing solutions etc etc and not make any progress because php wont immediately take into effect your changes. This can lead you into stumbling  around from one solution to the next, constantly changing your script and it can feel like you are in a maze.

There are ways to stop php from caching specific files. But the problem was php itself, with its misleading error report, and two with its caching of problems and excluding solutions.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using ???

Answer (score 2):

You are having case sensitivity issue. Most likely you moved form `windows environment` to `Linux`

If your file is `mysql.processing.PHP` `require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/mysql.processing.php` would work on a windows + apache  server but fail on Linux + apace

use the following to get the actual file name

```
var_dump(scandir(__DIR__));
```

Please run this simple test

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$name = "mysql.processing.php";
$file = __DIR__ . "/mysql.processing.php";
$dir = scandir(__DIR__);
$func = array("file_exists","is_file","is_readable");

echo "<pre>";
foreach ( $func as $fun ) {
    if (! $fun($file)) {
        echo $fun, " - Failed ", PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo $fun, " - Failed ", PHP_EOL;
    }
}

if (! in_array(basename($file), $dir)) {
    echo basename($file), " in_array Error", PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo basename($file), " in_array OK", PHP_EOL;
}

if (! in_array($name, $dir)) {
    echo $name, " in_array Failed", PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo $name, " in_array Ok", PHP_EOL;
}

if ($name !== basename($file)) {
    echo $name, " basename Failed", PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo $name, " basename OK", PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: I tried and it gives the exact same error.

Comment: please run the above simple test ...

Comment: it returns `in_array Error`. But nothing else. So the file definitely exists. It's weird php at it again. Plus one for effort.

Comment: Can you add `var_dump($dir)` to pastebin let me see ... your case is very intresting

Comment: Please run `var_dump(in_array("mysql.processing.php", $dir));` and `var_dump(in_array("IMEXporter.class.php", $dir));` and tell me what you get ???

Comment: `bool(true) bool(true)`. They are there Baba, I assure you :)

Comment: but you told me that it returd `in_array Error` before something is not that .. i would write a better testing script hold on

Comment: Please run the new test and paste the full result in paste bin ....

Comment: @Sofiane Merah  waiting .. how did it go ??

Comment: http://pastebin.com/3xV2yABB. Sorry for the wait. I actually just solved it. posting answer in just a sec

Comment: @Sofiane Merah Your current result does not tally with your info .. but it would be interesting to see what you discovered

Comment: posted it. Thanks so much for the help Baba. You deserve more rep for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the error message the capitalization on the filename is not the same as in the require line you posted... are you sure it's not a typo?

Comment: fixed the typo, but the problem persists.

Comment: Copy the file path in the error message to the clipboard.  Then run ls -l on the pasted file path.

Comment: yep, I actually tried that already. prints out the file meta info on the shell. Still wont find it on the php script. And again both are in the same directory.

Comment: Are you getting this running PHP from the command line, or is it through a webserver?

Comment: The original error? From a php script on the server.

Comment: Try running a test script that does the failing require from the command line.  i.e. using "php pathToTestScript".  If it works from the command line then it's related somehow to the webserver environment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that your php are not in the same folder, you cannot include a .php  from  a URL or another folder. You can include a php if it is on the same path or in a subfolder that is on your path. Sorry for my english but I think that you're going to understand what I'm saying.